# Можно ли создавать квиток о reject писем?

Tags: linux, debian, email, postfix, dovecot

Настроил postfix+dovecot+clamav всё работает и антивирус удаляет заражённые письма. Можно ли как-то настроить так, чтобы заражённые письма не удалялись, а просто помечались как вирусные изменением Заголовка?
Или можно как-то вместо удалённых писем отправлять квиток, что вам было письмо с вирусом, но мы его прибили?